# How to Track References in Copy-On-Write VM Mappings

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory, xv6

I'm trying to modify [xv6-riscv](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv) to perform a copy-on-write mapping when executing `fork()`.

Most sources I can find online suggest to keep track of how many processes currently are able to read from a given copy-on-write page in the PTE. Once that number reaches 0 (either by `kill()`ing or `exec()`ing every process that was forked or just whenever every process has made a write reference), then you delete the page.

However, it's not clear to me how you would actually implement this. The PTE is of a fixed size, and the vast majority of bits, especially in RISCV, are reserved for other purposes, so storing the number of references in the actual PTE feels impractical.

Furthermore, how would you synchronize this information across page tables? Each process has unique PTE's, even if they point to the same physical page. Updating the reference count on the current process's PTE for a physical page will not give any information to the other processes.

My idea was to create a sort of page table tree which would dynamically grow as processes `fork()` and shrink as processes call `exec()` or `kill()`, but this doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere, and it's pretty convoluted, so I wanted to explore simpler options.